# How to get a db session at Pyramid app initialisation

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I'd like to do some database checks before initalising the pyramid app, but I'm not quite sure how to do that.

I could potentially create a fake request through the request factory and get the session from it. But I suspect there's a better way. Can I get a temporary transaction from the app, or the configurator?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the cookiecutter then it's pretty straightforward. The session factory is stored in `config.registry['dbsession_factory']` and you can grab it and use it to make sessions whenever you want, including at config-time. A good way to do it is with a temporary transaction manager, but it's not required.

```
import transaction

from myapp.models import get_tm_session

def main(...):
    config.include('myapp.models')
    tm = transaction.TransactionManager(explicit=True)
    with tm:
        dbsession = get_tm_session(config.registry['dbsession_factory'], tm)
        # do stuff, the "with tm" will invoke commit if there are no exceptions
```